# How can I route messages from a single RabbitMQ queue to separate methods?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, microservices

I've got a Spring Boot application. I've been designing microservices and these microservices communicate with each other via RabbitMQ. There is a channel service for directing my messages to related microservices. You can see the picture below.

[My channel and microservices picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5PBh.png)

Channel is directing messages to microservice 1, but microservice 1 should get my message to a specific method, for example, `getById()` method or `createAThing()` method.

How can I route my message to the related listener method?

Here is my code that consumes queue:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "my-single-queue")
public void createObjectByMessage(Message message) {
    // Create object with message
}

@RabbitListener(queues = "my-single-queue")
public void getByIdByMessage(Message message) {
    // Get object with message ID
}
```

Or, how can I consume the message from the same queue but using a different routing key? I have no config class. I'm using `@RabbitListener` annotation.

Comment: Take a look at `@QueueBinding` where you can specify the routing key as part of the configuration. There are more details in the documentation [Annotation-driven Listener Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#async-annotation-driven).